# In Qualtrics, how can I specify acceptable date ranges as a response to a survey item?

Tags: qualtrics

For example, if I want to ask the date that an event occurred in the past, how can I prevent the survey taker from entering a date in the future?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no built-in way to do this in Qualtrics. You'll have to write a JavaScript to do it.

Comment: Any advice on what the code would look like?  Thanks!

Comment: That isn't how StackOverflow works. It isn't a free programming service.

Comment: In theory, you could use regex custom validation to achieve this as well.